# BackboneJS Use different URL for Model save (Create / Update)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a Backbone Model which I save as below;

```
this.model.save(myJson, {
    url: "person/" + self.options.someId + "/create",
    success: function() {
        //
    }
})
```

Now there are 2 UI functionalities (Create/Edit)
I want a different URL to be set for each of these (Create/Edit)

So I'll have 2 urls;

```
Create : url: "person/" + self.options.someId + "/create"

Edit : url: "person/" + self.options.someId + "/edit"
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Generally its a better idea to stick with the convention and use `POST` for create and `PUT` for update on the same URL.

Comment: Yes, I do try to...but in this case, the APIs are different coz of some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use in my models, and works fine. Hope that helps.

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/api/mymodel/',
    idAttribute: 'id',
"sync": syncMyModel
});

function syncMyModel(method, model, options){
    if(method=='create'){
        options.url = model.url;
        }else{
            options.url = model.url + model.get('id') + '/';
        }
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
};
```